# JsonConvert.Deserialize JsonResult from MVC Action

Tags: c#, json.net

Should be simple! How can I accomplish the following?

```
JsonResult result = JsonConvert.Deserialize(CheckPlan());
```

Where CheckPlan() returns this:

```
return Json(new { success = success }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I am unable to parse the success boolean value returned by the JsonResult. I have tried to put `<Dictionary<string,string>>` right after Deserialize but it was balking on the syntax. Used like a type vs. a variable, etc.,etc.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 4.0 or above, you can use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject((string)CheckPlan().Data);

Console.WriteLine(result.success);
```

If you dont want `dynamic`, you can create a custom class with a `success` boolean property:

```
public class Foo
{
     [JsonProperty("success")]
     public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
Foo result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>((string)CheckPlan().Data);
Console.WriteLine(result.Success);
```

Comment: It's great and seems like it should work! but it won't compile. Here is what I did  JsonResultSuccess result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResultSuccess>(CheckPlan());  compiler says has some invalid arguments and cannot convert JsonResult to string.

Comment: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<project.Core.Models.JsonResultSuccess>(string)' cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' to 'string'

Comment: Now I'm getting this! Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType3`1[System.Boolean]' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Seems like it should be simpler. When I tried JsonResult result = CheckPlan() - that alone worked, but I couldn't access the value. Not sure why it's saying anonymous type now.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old post but I had exactly the same problem, which I solved as follows:

No need to use the deserializer!

```
dynamic result = CheckPlan().Data;    
Console.WriteLine(result.success);
```

In my case I was writing a unit test for an MVC controller method. Since the test methods are in their own project I had to give them access to the internals of the MVC project so that the `dynamic` could access the properties of the result's `Data` object.  To do this add the following line to `AssemblyInfo.cs` in the MVC project:

```
// Allow the test project access to internals of MyProject.Web
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.Test")]
```

Comment: How does everybody have .Data in their example?  I don't have that property popup in Intillisense from my JsonResult?